# I am getting ORA-01008: not all variables bound : Error when I am trying to read a oracle DB via SQLPagingQueryProviderFactoryBean

Tags: oracle, jdbc, spring-batch, batch-processing, jdbctemplate

Below is the snippet of the code of Spring boot JDBC item reader which call paging Query query provider.

final SqlPagingQueryProviderFactoryBean testVar = new SqlPagingQueryProviderFactoryBean(); SqlPagingQueryProviderFactoryBean.setDataSource(dataSource); SqlPagingQueryProviderFactoryBean.setSelectClause("select *"); SqlPagingQueryProviderFactoryBean.setFromClause("from "+ tableName); SqlPagingQueryProviderFactoryBean.setWhereClause("where processtime is NULL AND RECORN_NUM BETWEEN :startPos AND :endPos) return ..

Error : Org.springframework.jdbc.uncategorizedSQLException : StatementCallBack; uncategorized SQLException for SQL [ SELECT * From ( SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE processtime is NULL AND RECORN_NUM BETWEEN :startPos AND :endPos order by RECORD_NUM <=100]; SQL state [72000]; error code[10008]: ORA-10008: not all variables bound; nested Exception

I am trying to read the data from the oracle table via spring boot batch job using a JDBC item reader.

Answer (score 0):

First, SQL keywords like `select`, `from`, etc can be omitted.

The problem is that you are not providing sorting keys. You need to provide a sort key, as mentioned in the Javadoc of [AbstractSqlPagingQueryProvider](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/current/api/org/springframework/batch/item/database/support/AbstractSqlPagingQueryProvider.html). This impacts the way SQL queries are generated.

If you declare the `SqlPagingQueryProviderFactoryBean` as a bean, the validation of sort keys should be triggered and you would have an exception earlier at configuration time.